# Get PublicKey from key bytes not knowing the key algorithm

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

I have a byte array containing an encoded public key.
I don't know the key algorithm.
And I want to get the PublicKey object.

What I have got is:

```
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.AsymmetricKeyParameter;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.util.PublicKeyFactory;

AsymmetricKeyParameter keyParameters = PublicKeyFactory.createKey(keyBytes);
```

The keyParameters class can be RSAKeyParameters, ECPublicKeyParameters, ... so now I can know the key algorithm.

And then:

```
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(keyAlgorithm);
X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
```

But I don't know if there's a more direct way to get the PublicKey. 
I mean, is there a direct way to get PublicKey from key bytes without the need to get first AsymmetricKeyParameter (and without the need to manually decode the key bytes) ?

Comment: Do you know the length of the key, EC keys are generally shorter than RSA keys. Have you examined the byte array in a hex editor or even plain text editor?

Comment: What is the problem with your code? As you say the keyAlgorithm can be known using the class of AssymetricKeyParameters. In my knowledge there is no direct convert from   AssymetricKeyParameters   to java `PublicKey`

Comment: It seems like a chicken-or-the-egg problem (to get the key you must know the algorithm, but you'll know the algorithm only after having the key object). I don't see other way to solve it than doing `if (keyParameters instanceof RSAKeyParameters) { use RSA algorithm }` and so on

Comment: @pedrofb Using PublicKeyFactory.createKey(keyBytes) I can get an AsymmetricKeyParameter of the proper type. What I mean is if there is a way to directy get the PublicKey from keyBytes without the need to get before the AsymmetricKeyParameter and check its class. That is, something like PublicKey publicKey = PublicKeyFactory.generateKey(keyBytes);

Comment: @zaph Yes, I can know the algorithm of the key editing its bytes. But what I'm searching is an automatic way to get the PublicKey object from any type of keyBytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a direct way (using Bouncy Castle API):

```
public PublicKey publicKeyParse(byte[] publicKeyBytes) {
            InputStream pgpIn = PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(publicKeyBytes));
            PGPObjectFactory pgpFact = new PGPObjectFactory(pgpIn, new JcaKeyFingerprintCalculator());
            PGPPublicKeyRing pgpSecRing = (PGPPublicKeyRing) pgpFact.nextObject();
            PGPPublicKey publicKey = pgpSecRing.getPublicKey();
            JcaPGPKeyConverter converter = new JcaPGPKeyConverter();
            Provider bcProvider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
            converter.setProvider(bcProvider);
            return converter.getPublicKey(publicKey);
    }
```

Comment: Is this still relevant? I get an error where pgpFact does not accept 2 parameters, but just 1. The compiler forces me to delete new JcaKeyFingerprintCalculator()

Comment: Check your bouncycastle version.

Comment: Versions 1.59 or 1.61 of bouncycastle have this 2 parameters constructor, see: https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pgdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/PGPObjectFactory.html#PGPObjectFactory-java.io.InputStream-org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.KeyFingerPrintCalculator-

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid there is no direct way. It is needed to inspect the class created by bouncycastle to know the algorithm (better option than parse the key manually) and build the `PublicKey` using `X509EncodedKeySpec`

Something like this

```
 //load key with Bouncycastle 
 AsymmetricKeyParameter keyParameters = PublicKeyFactory.createKey(keyBytes);

 //get algorithm inspecting the created class
 String keyAlgorithm = extractKeyAlgorithm(keyParameters);

 //get public key
 KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(keyAlgorithm);
 X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
 PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
```

---

```
 public String extractKeyAlgorithm(AsymmetricKeyParameter keyParameters){

       if (keyParameters instanceof RSAKeyParameters){
             return "RSA";
       } else if (keyParameters instanceof DSAKeyParameters){
             return "DSA";
       } else {
          ...
       }
 }
```

Each instance of `AsymmetricKeyParameter` has the parameters of the key, and they could be provided to the constructor of X509EncodedKeySpec in this [way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42862872/6371459). But I think above code is simpler